# Determining minimum problem size "n"

Tags: asymptotics

my problem is:

The execution time of the first algorithm can be given as a function of the
input size $n$ as $f(n) = n^{1.5} \log^2 n$.
The execution time of the second algorithm is similarly: $g(n) = n^2$.

Find the minimum problem size $n$ needed so that the fastest asymptotic 
algorithm becomes faster than the other one.

I am aware that $f(n)$ is faster than $g(n)$ since the execution time of the first function is much lower for most n's. I also know that $g(n)$ is the fastest asymptotically, but I do not understand when the asymptotic algorithm becomes faster than the other one since it appears that $g(n)$ will never be faster than $f(n)$ according to graphs.

Comment: What makes you say the second algorithm is the fastest asymptotically?

Comment: When I plot it, it appears to approach an "asymptote", albeit I have no idea what the asymptote would be, earlier than the other function. I could be misunderstanding the whole concept though...

Comment: I think that's the case. I wouldn't say the graph of $y=x^2$ approaches an asymptote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^2$ eventually dominates $n^{1.5} log^2 n$.

You want to solve for $n$ (find the values of $n$ where the execution time functions intersect), and then take the ceiling of the largest value. Equations in $x$ involving products of $x$ and $e^x$ are solved using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function%20Lambert%20W%20function). See [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E(1.5)(logn)%5E2%20%3D%20n%5E2) for a visualization.